# Cocos2d iAd banner appearing v3

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, iad

I am following this iAd banner tutorial [Cocos2d_iAd_v3](https://app.box.com/s/fr5ya0hyf322gfd7gntx) and it works. I am now trying to get rid of the button that toggle the "Show banner" and "Hide banner" and only show the iAd banner only; however it doesn't seem to work. 
How can I display the iAd banner without using the button to turn it on and off?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The iAd network is sending ads continuously, so as long as the banner view is visible (i.e. is placed in a visible region of the screen), you're going to see the banner and the ads always. Therefore, if during the initialization of the game (e.g. in AppDelegate) you create the banner view object, it should be there forever. However, you must consider hiding the banner view if an ad is not loaded, which you can check with the property "bannerLoaded" property.

I recently posted an entry in my [blog](http://becomingindiedev.blogspot.com.es/2015/02/integrating-iad-in-cocos2d-x-v3x.html) on integrating iAd and Cocos2d. You might want to give it a read.